# Elements responsive align

Tags: android, xml

Trying to places 3 elements on a line, the first and last elements close to left and right margin, the second element must dynamically occupy the central space.
This example is not responsive, it works on the emulator but does not fit in the real device. Looking to figure out how tu use Relative and Linear Layouts

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    tools:context="com.example.wavemaker.MainActivity">
    <RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView

        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"

        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="PITCH"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/freqSlider" />


        <com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
            android:id="@+id/freqSlider"
            android:layout_width="246dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/freqTextSlider"

            android:stepSize="1"
            android:value="36"
            android:valueFrom="0"
            android:valueTo="127"
            app:labelBehavior="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/freqTextSlider"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"



            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text="36"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"


            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"

            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text="DECAY" />

        <com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
            android:id="@+id/decSlider"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:value="74"
            app:labelBehavior="gone"
            android:stepSize="1"
            android:valueFrom="0"
            android:valueTo="127"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/decTextSlider"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"



            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text="74"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"


        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"

        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="RAMP"/>

    <com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
        android:id="@+id/rampSlider"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:value="54"
        app:labelBehavior="gone"
        android:stepSize="1"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="127"
        />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rampTextSlider"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"



            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text="54"/>
    </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
       >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/trigger"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="#999999"
            />




    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```